# Assertion error check with If else python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, assertion

From the following code if the 4th If block satisfies, then the remaining statements under the same will be executed else the assertion statements will get executed. Now By any chance if any of the assertion statement fails with an Assertion error, I want to execute the Same code block which is under the 4th If block. How to do it?

```
def step_impl(context, status, exp_date, owner, reg_date, man_yr, vchl_make, vchl_code):
    if context.conv_exp_date < context.conv_expnd_date:
        if context.conv_reg_date >= '01-09-2018':
            if man_yr == context.expctd_manu_year:
                if not context.json_response:
                    print("empty response")
                    json_data = context.payload
                    sys.stdout = open("OD_Plans.log", "a")
                    print("Previous Policy Status=" + " " + status)
                    print("expiry date=" + " " + exp_date)
                    print("Owner=" + " " + owner)
                    print("Registration Date=" + " " + reg_date)
                    print("Manufacturing Year=" + " " + man_yr)
                    print("Veichle Maker=" + " " + vchl_make)
                    print("Maker Code=" + " " + vchl_code)
                    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2))
                else:
                    assert context.json_response is not None
                    assert float(context.json_response[0]['base_premium']) > float(1)
                    assert float(context.json_response[0]['total_premium']) > float(1)
                    assert float(context.json_response[0]['tax']) > float(1)
                    print(context.json_response[0]["tax"])
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Use a try/except construct to handle any error gracefully.

Comment: Note: since `'01-09-2018'` is a string, comparing for "dates" even dates as strings might not make sense. For example: try `'01-09-2018' > '01-09-1018'`

Comment: @mechanical_meat I have tried using try except but even after genuine failure, the test is shown as pass in the allure report. Also my objective is to run the code block of the 4th If statement if any assertion error occurs

Answer (score 0):

To catch assertion errors, you can have a try/except block inside your `else` block:

```
else:
    try:
        assert context.json_response is not None
        assert float(context.json_response[0]['base_premium']) > float(1)
        assert float(context.json_response[0]['total_premium']) > float(1)
        assert float(context.json_response[0]['tax']) > float(1)
        print(context.json_response[0]["tax"])

    except AssertionError:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: if use try except, then even after failure, the test is shown as pass. Also my objective is to run the code block of the 4th If statement if any assertion error occurs